# Hacer winkear el texto de la consola de Node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, consola

Me gustaría conseguir que el texto de la consola de Node.js parpadeara (winkeara), algo similar a cambiarle el color que ya  he visto como se hace:

console.log("%cSoy de color azul", "color: blue; font-style: italic");

console.log("%cEspaña","background: red; color: yellow");

Muchas gracias

Comment: *Winkear* no es una palabra que exista en inglés ni en castellano. Por otro lado, ¿qué has intentado/investigado? Saludos.

Comment: Querras haber dicho blinkear, que tampoco es una palabra existente, pero proviene del verbo blink del ingles el cual si existe, asi que blinkear si existiera traduciria algo como "parpadear".

Comment: Lo que quiero es el texto aparezca y desaparezca, parpadear, creí que se decía winkear. Muchas gracias